# Uploader Plugin button not working octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I downloaded and set up the [Uploader](https://octobercms.com/plugin/responsiv-uploader) plugin but for some reason the button is not working. When i click on it nothing happens. This is my set up.
On the page

```
[imageUploader]
maxSize = "2"
fileTypes = "*"
deferredBinding = "1"
==

<?php
function onInit()
{
    $this->imageUploader->bindModel('allimage', new Advert);
}
?>`
==

{{ form_open() }}
    <!-- File uploader -->
    {% component 'imageUploader' %}
{{ form_close() }}
```

Then in my component file

```
public function onSubmit(){
 $advert = new Advert();
       $advert->title = Input::get('title');
       $advert->user_id = Auth::getUser()->id;
       $advert->save(null, post('_session_key'));
}
```

In my model i have

```
  public $attachMany = [
        "allimage" => "System\Models\File"

         ];
```

The upload button just doesn't respond. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You might need `{% framework extras %}` and jquery for it to work. Also looking at the plugin's docs what happens when you do `<form></form>`instead of `{% form_open() %}{%form_close() %}`.

What does the inspector console or network show when you try to upload?

Where do you get your 'title'? From a slug?

Instead of using someone else's plugin why don't you create your own form?

In your component.php file:

```
public function onSubmit() {
    $advert->title = Input::get('title');
    $advert->allimage = Input::file('image');
    $advert->user_id = Auth::getUser()->id;
    $advert->save(null, post('_session_key'));
}
```

In your CMS page or Component default / partial .htm file:

```
{{ form_open({files: true, request: 'onSubmit'}) }} 
    <div>
       <input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
     <!--File Input--> 
     <input type="file" name="image"> 
     <!--Submit/Upload Button--> 
     <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
 {{ form_close() }}
```